# Creating a directory in project's root directory when package is installed via npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, post-install

I have created an npm package that is supposed to create a directory in the project's root directory (using postinstall) when it is installed via npm.

Currently I have a script (createConfigDir.js) that is supposed to create the `config` directory:

```
const path = require('path');
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
const projectPath = path.join(process.cwd(), '../../config');

mkdirp.sync(projectPath)
```

then in the package.json under script I do:

```
scripts{
    "postinstall":"node ./scripts/createConfigDir.js"
}
```

When the package gets installed the config folder gets created but outside the project's root directory.  If I change the path from `const projectPath = path.join(process.cwd(), '../../config');` to `const projectPath = path.join(process.cwd(), '../config');` the folder gets created inside my package. How can I create the directory inside the project's root directory?

What am i doing wrong?  Is this possible in node?